# How to get rid of duplicate rows preserving information into another column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I am trying to get rid of duplicates from a dataset and I just found out that the rows are not exactly the same. Thus, I am trying to preserve the information and generate another column. For example, suppose I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d"),
                color = c("red", "blue", "green", "blue", "green","red"))

> df
  id color
1  a   red
2  a  blue
3  b green
4  c  blue
5  c green
6  d   red
```

Now, I would like to have no repetitive ids, thus I would like the extra information to be on another column. The result should be something like this:

```
> df2
  id color color2
1  a   red   blue
2  b green       
3  c  blue  green
4  d   red
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do this with `tidyverse` packages

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(n = row_number(),
         .by = id) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = n,
    names_prefix = 'color_',
    values_from = color
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   id    color_1 color_2
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 a     red     blue   
#> 2 b     green   <NA>   
#> 3 c     blue    green  
#> 4 d     red     <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Seth! Thank you so much for the answer. The code you provided works on the example, but when I am applying on my actual data it does not get rid of the duplicated row, but it generates another column. Have you got an idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Hi Victor Shin. Is it possible to modify the example data to capture what is happening with your real data? Are there the equivalent of multiple rows with the same `id` and `color`?

Comment: I figured out what was happening. There were other columns with different information. So, to keep it in the example, color was not the only column with different information. There was another column also with different info.

Answer (score 1):

```
aggregate (color~ id, data =df, FUN=paste0, simplify=FALSE)

  id       color
1  a   red, blue
2  b       green
3  c blue, green
4  d         red
```

- `color~ id` : formula
- `data` : your datas
- `FUN=paste0` : the function applied
- `simplify=FALSE`: a logical indicating whether results should be simplified to a vector or matrix if possible.

But you're right it's only with string. The Seth answer is with different columns.

Comment: thank you! I guess it works too. I wouldn't like the information to be on the same column. But with this I could extract the extra into another column.